# Github actions "always()" condition not working as expected?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am interested in why this always() condition is not behaving as expected in a Github workflow.

I have a core pipeline, which works just fine. If the secondary workflow fails, the tertiary still runs but only if boolean output from secondary workflow == true.

Within the secondary pipeline, the output step is supposed to run only if a boolean input is set to true. Although I have used the exact same syntax, it only seems to run if the condition is always() rather than always() &&.

This is the core pipeline (which works):

```
name: Core Pipeline
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs: 
      boolean: 
        description: 'boolean'
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean 

jobs:
  secondary-workflow:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/secondary-workflow.yaml
    with:
      boolean: true 
  tertiary-workflow:
    needs: secondary-workflow
    uses: ./.github/workflows/tertiary-workflow.yaml
    if: always() && needs.secondary-workflow.outputs.boolean == 'true'
```

This is secondary-workflow (doesn't work as intended):

```
on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs: 
      boolean: 
        description: 'Boolean'
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean 
    outputs: 
      boolean: 
        description: "Test Output"
        value: ${{ jobs.job-4.outputs.boolean }}

jobs:
  job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: job 1 
        run: echo 'This job runs'
  job-2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-1
    steps:
      - name: job 2
        run: echo 'This job runs'
  job-3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job-1, job-2]
    steps:
      - name: Exit 
        run: echo "This job fails"; exit 1 
  job-4:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job-1, job-2, job-3]
    if: always() && inputs.boolean == 'true' (ADDING THE && CAUSES THE JOB TO BE SKIPPED) 
    steps:
      - id: setOutput
        run: echo "boolean=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT; echo "OUTPUT_SET"
    outputs:
      boolean: ${{ steps.setOutput.outputs.boolean }}
```

My question is, why does adding a second condition in addition to always() work for the core pipeline but not for the secondary pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `always() && inputs.boolean == true`, or shorter, `always() && inputs.boolean`? `inputs.boolean == 'true'` is comparing a boolean to a string, and on type mismatch, both are [converted to numbers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators), resulting in testing `1 == naN`, which is false.

Comment: I've gone with the first without quotes, and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare

```yaml
if: always() && inputs.boolean == 'true'
```

you're comparing a boolean to a string. On type mismatch, [actions coerce the operands to numbers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators); `true` becomes `1`, and `'true'` (the string) becomes `NaN`, and `1 == NaN` is false. To fix, you can compare to a boolean literal instead of a string:

```yaml
if: always() && inputs.boolean == true
```

or you should be able to just check the boolean on its own:

```yaml
if: always() && inputs.boolean
```

As for why the seemingly identical condition works in one place and not in the other, my guess is that the input parameter in the reusable workflow is typed as a boolean, whereas `needs.secondary-workflow.outputs.boolean` is a string, so comparison to `'true'` works.